# Python Gtk3 controlling button size

Tags: python, button, size, gtk3

The button size should be controlled by packing HBox in VBox but my two buttons still have size depending on text:

```
    first=Gtk.VBox()
    second=Gtk.HBox()
    third=Gtk.VBox()
    fourth=Gtk.HBox()
    but1=Gtk.Button(label="any title")
    first.pack_start(second,False,False,0)
    third.pack_start(fourth,False,False,0)        
    first.pack_start(but1,False,False,0)
    self.data_wp="title of label"
    self.label_data=Gtk.Label(label=self.data_wp)
    Gtk.Widget.set_size_request(but1,85,15)
    but2=Gtk.Button(label=self.data_wp)
    Gtk.Container.add(but2,self.label_data)
    Gtk.Widget.set_size_request(but2,85,15)
```

What am I doing wrong? I add button title from label but it shoudn't be the problem, and I tried to set title directly on button - nothing changed. I tried to use only one set of VBox,HBox, but it gave no effect too.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to resize the button using the set_size_request() method of the Gtk.Widget. But set_size_request() only set the minimum size of the widget, so it can still be larger.

I don't know if there is a method to resize the button, but there are the properties width-request and height-request of the Gtk.Widget that you can use.
In your code, it would be:
`bt1.set_property("width-request", 85)`
`bt1.set_property("height-request", 15)`